# Return row with column values or missing multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query as follows in latest version of SQL Server:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Uom s 
INNER JOIN catalogue l ON l.Uom = s.SAPUom 
WHERE l.Id IN (3, 4) 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN s.compid IS NOT NULL OR s.supplierid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

with an output like this:

[image]

If there is a `CompId` and `SupplierId` uom mapping in the table (row 1 and not row 2), the query should return that UOM **else** return the uom that is NULL.

Row 3 does not have a specified uom (`compId/SupplierId`) in the table and needs to be returned too.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want one row per `SAPUom`.  If so, you can use this trick:

```
select top (1) with ties s.*
from Uom s inner join
     catalogue l
     on l.Uom = s.SAPUom 
where l.Id in (3, 4) 
order by row_number() over (partition by s.SAPUom
                            order by (CASE WHEN s.compid is not null OR s.supplierid is not null THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                           );
```

Comment: It returns the same result as before but I will look into row_number(). Thanks

Comment: @Kevin . . . I left out the trick, the `top (1) with ties`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 3rd row I think you could use UNION ALL to add the rows from table Uom which do not have a corresponding row in the catalog.

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Uom s 
     INNER JOIN
     catalogue l ON l.Uom = s.SAPUom 
WHERE l.Id IN (3, 4)) 
union all
SELECT s.* 
FROM Uom s 
WHERE not exists (select 1 from catalogue c where c.Uom = s.SAPUom);
```